# The error I get when I want to save some data with Userdefaults

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I'm trying to save some Data using Userdefaults and everything work perfectly until I tap the button to save the dates. It's a basic app for save a date.

code in viewDidLoad

```
let storedName = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "personName")
    let storedDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "personDate")
    
    if let newName = storedName as? String{
        nameLabel.text = newName
    }
    
    if let newDate = storedDate as? String{
        birthdayLabel.text = newDate
```

code in Save button

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(nameTextField!, forKey: "personName")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(birthdayTextField, forKey: "personDate")
    
    nameLabel.text = "Name: \(nameTextField.text!)"
    birthdayLabel.text = "Birthday: \(birthdayTextField.text!)"
```

and the error I get

> Thread 1: "Attempt to insert non-property list object <UITextField: 0x7fea4d02ca00; frame = (20 85; 374 34); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002cb65b0>; placeholder = Name; borderStyle = RoundedRect; background = <_UITextFieldSystemBackgroundProvider: 0x6000022fa7c0: backgroundView=<_UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundViewNeue: 0x7fea4c7107c0; frame = (0 0; 374 34); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000022fa7e0>>, fillColor=(null), textfield=<UITextField 0x7fea4d02ca00>>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000022fa580>> for key personName"

Comment: You are trying to save the `UITextField` object. What you need is to save its `text` property. `nameTextField.text!`

Comment: Btw `UserDafaults` has a method called [string(forKey:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416700-string). No need to use `object(forKey:)` and then cast from `Any` to `String`